# Azure data factory file creation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I have a basic requirement where I want to append time stamp to file extracted from sql db and put it in blob.i use utcnow() and it creates a timestamp with T and all which I dont need.

any format expression to get date and just time??

New to javascript expressions as I am from ssis background

Help appreciated

Comment: where did you want to append the timestamp to, to file name or file content?

Comment: to the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do that is copy and create a new blob with a new name concat with the timestamp.

Data Factory doesn't support rename the blob.

I only succeed with one file.

You can follow my steps:

1. Using lookup activity to get the timestamp from SQL database.
2. Using Get metadata to get the blob name from Storage.
3. Using Copy data activity to copy and create new file name blob.

**Pileline preview:**

[image]

**Lookup preview:**
[image]

Get metadata and Source Dataset:
[image]

[image]

**Copy data activity Source setting:**

[image]

**Copy data activity Sink setting:**

Add parameter to set the new file name in source datasaet:

[image]

Using expression to create the new file with the filename and timestamp:

```
@concat(split(activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName,'.')[0],activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.tt)
```

[image]

Then check the output file in the Blob Storage:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there no way where we can just append filename with time stamp....right now in dataset I am able to achieve this filename_@{utcnow()}....but I dont want all the UTC values like T and extra characters ....I want to format it into simple timestamp

Comment: @SankeertanSamrat yes, you could using subString expression to achieve that(), then concat the filename and the stamp like '2020-03-02'. ' You need to learn how to using the [expressions and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression in the destination file name, in the sink.

`toTimestamp(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd_HHmm_ss')`

Comment: hey thanks everyone for the response...I have been using filename_@{utcnow())...so using it like filename_@{toTimestamp(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd_HHmm_ss')...This should work right?

Comment: it says totimestamp is not recognized function at dataset level....only filename_@{utcnow()} is recognized....Here in the expression list it doesn't show timestamp